# Combine Select Statements

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am building a dashboard screen which requires multiple sql statements to return data. However all of these database calls are adding up in regards to performance.

As it stands now the code calls are online meaning I'm am making database calls inside my code. I would like to move all of the database calls to a stored procedure but I am not sure how to combine all of the database calls into one stored procedure to return multiple values as I have to display each of the values individually.

Can someone show me how to combine these select statements into one and return multiple values yo be used inside my code.

```
/*Pending Count */
Select Count(*)
FROM Issue
WHERE Issue.WorkerKeyFk =  lngWorkerKey
      And Issue.ClosedDate is Null

/* Get Today's Issue Count */             
Select Count(*)
FROM Issue
WHERE Issue.WorkerKeyFk =  lngWorkerKey
      And Issue.IssueDate =  FormatDateTime(dateTimes, DateFormat.ShortDate)

/* Over Due Issue Count */
Select Count(*) 
FROM Issue
WHERE Issue.WorkerKeyFk =  lngWorkerKey
      And Issue.DueDate <  FormatDateTime(dateTimes, DateFormat.ShortDate)
      And Issue.ClosedDate is null       

/*Get Closed Issue Count */
Select Count(*)
FROM Issue
WHERE Issue.WorkerKeyFk = lngWorkerKey
      And Issue.ClosedDate is not null
```

Comment: Why not use Union All?

Comment: I am not familiar with using unions. Would you be able to provide an example?

Comment: I modify your code as an answer with union all.  Just an FYI, if you using union all, all your select statement must have the same result set.

Comment: @zXSwordXz Great thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
SELECT
    Sum(Iif(Issue.IssueDate = FormatDateTime(dateTimes, DateFormat.ShortDate), 1, 0) as Today_Issue_Count
    , Sum(Iif(Issue.DueDate < FormatDateTime(dateTimes, DateFormat.ShortDate) And Issue.ClosedDate is null, 1, 0) as Overdue_Issue_Count
    , Sum(Iif(Issue.ClosedDate is not null, 1, 0) as Closed_Issue_Count
FROM Issue
    WHERE Issue.WorkerKeyFk = lngWorkerKey
```

That way you only have one resultset to deal with, and execution should be pretty quick on the server.

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a shot.

Comment: And I just noticed that my query missed the Pending Issue count - I think that happened when Marco edited your post to make the code look like code.  The logic for that item will be similar to the Closed_Issue_Count item - I leave it to you as an exercise ;)

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'm sure I can figure it out now that you've provided some great insight.

Comment: You're welcome - it's why we're here.  Be sure to let me know how things turn out.

zXSwordXz's approach is another good one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Count(*), 'Pending' as Count_Label
FROM Issue
WHERE Issue.WorkerKeyFk =  lngWorkerKey
      And Issue.ClosedDate is Null

Union All           
Select Count(*), 'Today' as Count_Label
FROM Issue
WHERE Issue.WorkerKeyFk =  lngWorkerKey
      And Issue.IssueDate =  FormatDateTime(dateTimes, DateFormat.ShortDate)

union all
Select Count(*), 'Overdue' as Count_Label
FROM Issue
WHERE Issue.WorkerKeyFk =  lngWorkerKey
      And Issue.DueDate <  FormatDateTime(dateTimes, DateFormat.ShortDate)
      And Issue.ClosedDate is null       

union all
Select Count(*), 'Closed' as Count_Label
FROM Issue
WHERE Issue.WorkerKeyFk = lngWorkerKey
      And Issue.ClosedDate is not null
```

Comment: If I were to use the union clause how would I access the results of the individual queries to be displayed within my application?

Comment: I would suggest including a label field in each of those selects, so that the client code doesn't have to know the query to use the numbers.  I've added that as an edit to the code that zXSwordXz posted - you'll see it as soon as it gets reviewed.

Comment: Thanks, Brian, I forget to add a label for him to differentiate the different results.